# Unexpected noise/pixels of render preview in Viewport Shading

Tags: modeling, rendering, eevee-render-engine, noise-reduction

I'm really new to Blender and started watching a playlist from Youtuber Blender Guru, the one about making a donut. Link is provided below to the specific video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTxBrjN1ugA

I've been following his instructions but for some reason, when I switched to Render View on Viewport Shading, my donut suddenly became super pixelated in some parts. I tried to look up solutions to this problem but couldn't find one about it - as I am new, I'm not quite familiar with the terminology for this sort of problem. I provided some screenshots below to help visualize what it looks like.

For specs, I am using the latest version of Blender(2.82A) and I'm on Windows. I'd appreciate any help I could get. Thank you!
[image: Image render from faraway]

[image: Image render from close up]

Comment: Hello :). This could be caused by unsupported hardware. Does it meet Blender's [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)?

Comment: @JachymMichal Yes, it does meet the minimum requirements - just checked with your link!